# Windows 8 - Adding to PATH through Control Panel

Tags: windows-8, path

In order to install Laravel I need to put *~/.composer/vendor/bin* into path.

Here is how I've done it but it does not work (homestead is still unrecognizable variable).

I'm on Windows 8. So I went to:

```
Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Environment Variables
```

Under *System Variables* I've searched for *Path* variable which was:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState
>   Komodo Edit 8\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\AMD
>   APP\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin

I've added *C:\Users\myname\composer\vendor\bin* to it and therefore changed it to:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActiveState
>   Komodo Edit 8\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\AMD
>   APP\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Users\myname\composer\vendor\bin

Please, take a look at the last words of this long piece of text. Are they written ok? Or should I write something else?

Besides, how do I check that Composer is indeed inside my *C\Users\myname* folder? The fact is: from wherever I run *composer -v* (with Git Bash or Windows CMD) I get a positive response. It looks like Composer is successfully installed but I can't actually see it anywhere as a folder.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say to add `.composer/vendor/bin/` and you've just added `composer/vendor/bin/` (missing the . [full stop/period])

Does the directory on Windows have a . in the directory name?

Comment: I've added: C:\Users\myname\composer\vendor\bin

Comment: yes, but is the directory .composer or just composer?

Comment: I see what you mean. I don't know weather it is .composer or composer because, as said, I do not see it anywhere.

Comment: .dot files will be hidden by default on Windows. See if these instructions help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/08/win8-howto-19-show-hidden-files-folders-and-drives.aspx

Comment: Ok, I've followed the instructions at the link you posted. I can now see also by default hidden folders. But there is no folder .composer in C:\Users\myname nor anywhere else. At least I do not see it.

Comment: Hi, again, I have installed Composer again with php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php command and it turned back that Composer is successfully installed into: C:\Users\myname\composer.phar. Is this of any help?